# Woocommerce - External/Affiliate Product Image and title to External Link (New tab)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate, woothemes

I'm starting with programming with wordpress and woocommerce. I need help after searching for Stack.

I need the images and titles of the products of my store to point to the affiliate link without going through the single post page. And that everything opens in a new tab.

Been following this thread: [Woocommerce - External/Affiliate Product Image to External Link (Buy url)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946495/woocommerce-external-affiliate-product-image-to-external-link-buy-url/49240660?noredirect=1#comment85484876_49240660)

I have used the Edit # 2 code from Sadoo and it works perfectly for me.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 15);

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_open', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_close', 10);

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_open(){
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
  if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) )
    echo '<a href="' . $product->get_product_url() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProductImage-link">';
}

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_close(){
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
  if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) )
    echo '</a>';
}
```

I just need the title to link like the image and everything opens in new tabs.

Can someone say how can I continue?

Thank you

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF73M.png)

Comment: If you want open link in a new tab then change one line of code to these echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $product->get_product_url() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProductImage-link">';
}   But can you please specify about title? What do you mean title like image?

Comment: Perfect! the images open in a new tab!
Excuse my definition. I want the name of the product also to point to the affiliate link.

I attach an image to make it more visual.

Thank you very much Oleg Apanovich. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open link attached to image in a new tab for a external products in your shop page then edit your code like these

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 15);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_open', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_close', 10);

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_open(){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . $product->get_product_url() . '" class="">';
    }
}

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_close(){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

Then if you want title will be opened in a new tab with external link than  add these overridden woocommerce function to your functions.php file of your theme too

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'external' ) ) {
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', $product->get_product_url(), $product );
        echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    } else {
        $link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_product_link', get_the_permalink(), $product );
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an cleaner approach to how you add `target="_blank"` to links on archive pages to open them in new tab:

```
function ns_open_in_new_tab($args, $product) 
{
    if( $product->is_type('external') ) {
        // Inject target="_blank" into the attributes array
        $args['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
    }    

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'ns_open_in_new_tab', 10, 2 );
```

Replace `ns_` part with your own namespace abbreviation.

Comment: better solution in my eyes. Thank you